# AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 on ios

Tags: react-native, aws-sdk

```
AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2
```

[image]

getting this error when uploading reaches 100% on iOS while android is working fine.

I am using `react-native-s3`. but it seems to be an issue with sdk or my bucket policy but I don't know how to fix this.

More info:
To upload, I am using CognitoCredentials, the region, IdentityPool, and sessionToken generated from our server.

EDIT:
This only happens on iOS. Android is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems my problem was wrong region. I don't know why Android works though.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is an S3 bucket policy issue, permissions. Below is an example policy script for s3.

```
<key>AWS</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CredentialsProvider</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CognitoIdentity</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Default</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>PoolId</key>
                    <string>us-west-2:xxxxx</string>
                    <key>Region</key>
                    <string>USWest2</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>S3TransferUtility</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Region</key>
                <string>**USEast1**</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: where do I add this? in Info.plist?

Comment: @Damathryx yes. did u figure it out? Im having this issue now.

Comment: @MaxNelson for me it was the incorrect region. i dont know why it was working on android though

Answer (score 1):

> Check your ARN at the time of adding policy to S3 bucket. It should be
> like
>
> arn:aws:s3:::yourBucketName/*
>
> if you are uploading in your bucket directly without any sub
> directory.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, however it's better to write my situation and solution. 
In my iOS (Swift) project, I was trying to upload a picture after login (using Cognito) and I got this error:

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)"
```

Everything seemed well on code below:

```
transferUtility.uploadData(
            data,
            key: "my-picture.png",
            contentType: "image/png",
            expression: expression,
            completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
                if let error = task.error {
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Error on upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }

                if let _ = task.result {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Upload Starting!")
                    }
                }

                return nil;
        }
```

The solution is on [AWS Amplify Storage documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage#storage-access). As stated there, I should have written  the key value like `key: "private/{user_identity_id}/my-picture.png"`

Maybe, it will help anybody in the future.

Comment: @iKayaktas can you explain more about your answer. I am facing this issue.

Comment: Hi Muhammad. How did you put uploading file name as key? Key value should include 'private/USER_ID/' before file name as stated here: key: "private/{user_identity_id}/my-picture.png"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the case for the issue was special symbols in the file name, in particular `%`. Filtering special symbols from the file name before uploading the file solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have config all region but i forget to set headerRequest and parameterRequest after i set its work for me

expression.setValue("public-read-write", forRequestHeader: "x-amz-acl")
expression.setValue("public-read-write", forRequestParameter: "x-amz-acl")

Comment: Still not working