# Upload file to S3 service 403 ERROR (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 2.) Swift iOS

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I tried to upload my file to S3 service vie AWSS3 SDK swift. 
My code:

---

```
    let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: Config.main.accessKey, secretKey: Config.main.secretKey)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, endpoint: AWSEndpoint(url: URL(string: Config.main.AWS_ENDPOINT)!), credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

let image = UIImage(named: "photo")!
let data: Data = image.pngData()!
let remoteName = generateRandomStringWithLength(length: 12) + "." + data.format
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(remoteName)
try! data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
upload(fileUrl: fileURL, fileData: data, fileName: remoteName, type: .image, completionHandler: {_ in})
```

---

```
func upload(fileUrl: URL, fileData: Data, fileName: String, type: FileTypes, completionHandler: @escaping (URL?) -> ()) {

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = { task, progress in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Progress = \(progress.completedUnitCount)/\(progress.totalUnitCount)")
        }
    }
    let util = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    util.uploadData(
        fileData,
        bucket: self.getBucket(type: type),
        key: "\(self.getDir(type: type))_\(fileName)",
        contentType: "image/png",
        expression: expression) { task, error in
            print("ERROR: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            print("response: \(task.response)")
            print("response: \(task.response)")

        }.continueWith { task in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("ERROR1: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return nil
    }
}
```

It returns me something like 5 times progress response and after that

> ERROR: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 2.)")
>
> response: Optional( { URL:
>   http://(bucket).(host)/image_L24i8RGCeAaj.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=59589007eea780cf27c5%2F20200131%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200131T125453Z&X-Amz-Expires=2999&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost&X-Amz-Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           186
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Fri, 31 Jan 2020 12:54:53 GMT"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           LeoFS
>       ); } })

Android app with same setup works perfect.

What is the solution of the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456903/awss3transferutilityerrordomain-code-2-on-ios)

Comment: @chirag90, but which region is valid?
I tried some and no another results

Comment: @PavloKharambura Use the S3 bucket region, where you have created your S3 bucket in your AWS account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having same issue. Everything was working fine on android, While IOS was not working with same configuration.

Then I contacted AWS support, and they told me iPhones Date and time is wrong. I just adjusted date and time to correct date and time and then tried to upload and it worked.

Comment: Hi Jignesh, I'm having the same issue and non of the solutions found in this web helped me. Can you give me more information how you solved this issue?

Comment: As mentioned, the date and time on my iPhone were incorrect. I set it up to correct date and time and then upload worked without any issues.

Comment: I think that The date we are getting in response is just UTC date.

Answer (score 1):

hi if you are not using custom endpoints, change this line:

`let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, endpoint: AWSEndpoint(url: URL(string: Config.main.AWS_ENDPOINT)!), credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)`

to:

`let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)`

and it will work just fine. The SDK can resolve the endpoint of the service by itself without providing an endpoint. You only need to provide an endpoint if you are using custom endpoints. It is also worth noting here that if you did want to pass the endpoint, you need to make sure you are passing the correct endpoint and us-east-1 for s3 has a special endpoint that does not include region as shown below:

`let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1,endpoint: AWSEndpoint(url: URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com")) , credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)`

Comment: are you sure your custom endpoint is set up correctly with the appropriate permissons?

Answer (score 1):

There is some useful info about this at https://medium.com/@lewisjkl/signing-aws4-31dcff1bf1f0, from Jeff Lewis.

It uses the `CryptoSwift` library; I'm working now to convert it to use the new `CryptoKit`.

Comment: This link bypasses the `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` to do its own authentication. That may be too much of a diversion of attention from your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just  check your device date and time. Because, AWS don't accept the wrong date or time.

Comment: This just repeats the accepted answer.